# Encode a string variable in non-alphanumeric order

Tags: label, encode, stata

I want to `encode` a string variable in such a way that assigned numerical codes respect the original order of string values (as shown when using `browse`).  Why? I need encoded variable labels to get the correct variable names when using `reshape wide`.

Suppose `var` is a string variable with no labels:

```
var      label(var)  
"zoo"    none  
"abc"    none
```

If you start with:

> encode var, gen(var2)

the labels are 1="abc" 2="zoo" as can be seen with

> label li

But I want **the labels sorted as they come**, as shown in `browse` for an unchanged order of variables later.

I didn't find an `encode` option in which the labels are added in the order I see when using `browse`.

My best idea is to do it by hand:

> ssc install labutil
>   labvalch var, f(1 2) t(2 1)

This is nice, but I have >50 list entries.

Other approach:  When using `reshape` use another order, but I don't think that works.

> reshape wide x, i(id) j(var)

I only found

> ssc install labutil
>   labmask regioncode, values(region)

as some alternative to `encode` but I'm not able to cope with strings using `labmask`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's a rule in Stata that string variables can't have value labels. Only numeric variables can have value labels. In essence, what you want as value labels are already in your string variable as string values. So, the nub of the problem is that you need to create a numeric variable with values in the right order.

Let's solve the problem in its easiest form: string values occur once and once only. So

```
gen long order = _n 
labmask order, values(var)
```

then solves the problem, as the numeric values 1, 2, ... are linked with the string values `zoo`, `abc`, whatever, which become value labels. Incidentally, a better reference for `labmask`, one of mine, is 
http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0034

Now let's make it more complicated. String values might occur once or more times, but we want the numeric variable to respect first occurrence in the data.

```
gen long order1 = _n
egen order2 = min(order1), by(var) 
egen order = group(order2) 
labmask order, values(var)
```

Here's how that works.

```
gen long order1 = _n
```

puts the observation numbers 1, 2, whatever in a new variable.

```
egen order2 = min(order1), by(var)
```

finds the first occurrence of each distinct value of `var`.

```
egen order = group(order2)
```

maps those numbers to 1, 2, whatever.

```
labmask order, values(var)
```

links the numeric values of `order` and the string values of `var`, which become its value labels.

Here is an example of how that works in practice.

```
. l, sep(0)

    +---------------------------------+
    |   var   order1   order2   order |
    |---------------------------------|
 1. |   zoo        1        1     zoo |
 2. |   abc        2        2     abc |
 3. |   zoo        3        1     zoo |
 4. |   abc        4        2     abc |
 5. |   new        5        5     new |
 6. | newer        6        6   newer |
    +---------------------------------+

. l, nola sep(0)

    +---------------------------------+
    |   var   order1   order2   order |
    |---------------------------------|
 1. |   zoo        1        1       1 |
 2. |   abc        2        2       2 |
 3. |   zoo        3        1       1 |
 4. |   abc        4        2       2 |
 5. |   new        5        5       3 |
 6. | newer        6        6       4 |
    +---------------------------------+
```

You would `drop order1 order2` once you have got the right answer.

See also `sencode` for another solution. (`search sencode` to find references and download locations.)

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I am sure you are right. It's easier for me to use commands I understand from the inside as well as the outside, here `labmask`.

Comment: Oh. I should have known there was simple solution. :) Thanks for the pointer to `labmask`.

Answer (score 3):

The user-written command `sencode` (super encode) by Roger Newson, and available running `ssc describe sencode` can be used for what you want. Instead of assigning numerical codes based on the alphanumeric order of the string variable, they can be assigned using the order in which the values appear in the original dataset.

```
clear all
set more off

*------- example data ---------

input str10 var
abc
zoo
zoo
zoo
elephant
elephant
abc
abc
elephant
zoo
end

*------- encode ---------------

encode var, generate(var2)
sencode var, generate(var3)

list, separator(0)
list, separator(0) nolabel
```

The variable `var3` is in the desired form. Contrast that with `var2`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an elegant solution, because I think that `levelsof` orders strings alphabetically.

As long as your list is unique this should work.

```
clear
input str3 myVar 
"zoo"
"abc"
"def"
end

* for reshape
generate iVar = 1
generate jVar = _n

* reshape to wide
reshape wide myVar, i(iVar) j(jVar)
list

* create label
local i = 0
foreach v of varlist myVar* {
    local ++i
    local myVarName = `v'
    label define myLabel `i' "`myVarName'", add
}

* reshape to wide
reshape long myVar, i(iVar) j(myVarEncoded)

* assign label
label value myVarEncoded myLabel
```